# Why does my graph look like this when I try to plot two variables onto the same plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: Result from using ggplot2]

You can create the dataframe using this code:

```
structure(list(year = c(1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969), DAI = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100), Severity = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 20, 50, 80, 90, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 30, 70)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

I want to create two plots in one area, and then I will estimate the area under each curve using the pracma package. The code I use to create the plot is:

```
  p2 <- ggplot(df4, aes(x=DAI, y=Severity, color=year)) + geom_line()
  p2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `year` in `factor`:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(year = c(1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969), DAI = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100), Severity = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 20, 50, 80, 90, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 30, 70)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))

ggplot(df,aes(x=DAI,y=Severity,color = factor(year)))+geom_line()
```